# How to get and change url when using jQuery.load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the url according to the menu pages, so to easily share a link to someone else, since each page has its own url name.

So, I have a function that loads the file content. But how to implement it with the url change also into the function?

```
<script>
    function getfile(data) {
        var file= data+'.html';
        $('#content').load(file);
    }
</script>
```

Here is the navigation using `onclick` function.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="getfile('profile')">Profile</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="getfile('about')">About</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="getfile('contact')">Contact</a> </li>    
</ul>


<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). The [`pushState` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29_method) will allow you to change the current page's URL, without reloading the content.

### Example:

```
<script>
    function getfile(data) {
        var file= data+'.html';
        $('#content').load(file);
        history.pushState(null, null, file);
    }
</script>
```

You may also be interested in [the `popstate` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_popstate_event), to detect when the browser travels back to the previous pages.

### Update:

In order to load files for a sub directory, you will need to know the path to the root directory for the site. Something like the following will work if the site is at the root directory.

```
<script>
    var rootPath = '/';
    function getfile(data) {
        var file= rootPath+data+'.html';
        $('#content').load(file);
        history.pushState(null, null, file);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank it's working if files in same directory,but problem if i call the file in another directory like : var file = 'files/'+data+'.html';

Comment: @qmnew In that case, you will need to know the root folder to prepend it to the `file` variable. If the page is at the root directory, you could use `/`. See updated answer.

Comment: yup, I have created the variable like this : var file = 'files/'+data+'.html'; 
but,the problem url become continuous repeated if click multiple time.

Comment: localhost/main/files/files/files/files/about.html

Comment: Oh,ok,that is working fine,I have just included '/' at front as you said,thank Alexander O'Mara